# Why can't I reverse a sequence of complex numbers in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to create a real-fft function in tensor flow for audio processing.  This involves removing the upper half of the fft since with real numbers the upper half of the fft is just the reversed complex conjugate of the bottom.  When I tried to create the inverse real fft I needed to reverse the sequence of complex numbers, take the conjugate and then concat it to the original complex tensor.  When I went to do this I got an error saying type complex64 is not supported for the reverse operation.  Therefore I had to implement it as follows `tf.conj(tf.complex(tf.reverse(tf.real(x), dims = (False, True)), tf.reverse(tf.imag(x), dims = (False, True)))))`.

This seems kind of inefficient and like a hack.  Is there any reason reverse should not be supported for complex types or is it just something the developers forgot to include?  Also is there a better way to do it?

Here is my full irfft function which operates on batches.  The input is not stored as a complex type.  It is stored in the format [re0, re2 ..., reN, im0, im1, ..., imN]

```
def irfft(x):
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    x = tf.complex(x[:, :x.get_shape()[-1].value // 2], x[:, x.get_shape()[-1].value // 2:])
    x = tf.concat(1, (x, tf.conj(tf.complex(tf.reverse(tf.real(x), dims = (False, True)), tf.reverse(tf.imag(x), dims = (False, True))))))
    return tf.real(tf.batch_ifft(x[:, :x.get_shape()[-1].value - 1]))
```

Comment: I agree. I see no reason why `tf.reverse()` shouldn't work for complex numbers. I suggest you either file an issue on Github, or, even better, add support and send a pull request :-)